# Order of a nontrivial fusion class

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Define a fusion class of a finite group G to be a set $F(x)=\{\phi(x):\phi\in$ Aut$(G)\}$ for some $x\in G$.

Now, suppose $G$ is a noncyclic group.  I want to say something about the order of each nontrivial fusion class of $G$.

I suppose I am just getting hung up on the fusion class versus the conjugacy class.  I know the difference between them (conjugacy class is over inner automorphisms whereas the fusion class is over all automorphisms) but when I am computing $|F_i|$, for each $i$, would I still consider $|G:C_g|$, where $C_g$ is the centralizer?  So would the order of each fusions class, since $G$ is noncyclic, just be $|G|$?

I feel like I am just overlooking something obvious.

Comment: $|F(1)|=1$ and $|F(x)|= |Aut(G)|/|Stab(x)|$ where $Stab(x)$ is a subgroup of $Aut(G)$. $Stab(F(x))$ is a normal subgroup of $Aut(G)$. For inner automorphisms $i_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ we get $Stab(x)\cap Inn(G)=C_x=\{g\in G,gx=xg\}$.

Comment: @reuns Ah, I see.  So then the sum of the orders of all he nontrivial fusion classes would be 2 times the number of nontrivial fusion classes, right?